# Excel using MATCH formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the formula `=MATCH(B4,B61:B88,-1)` in cell `C4`, this works perfectly when I type a value in B4. But when there is no value in `B4`, `C4` has the max value which is `28` but I need it to be `0` until I put something in B4.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the match in an IF:

```
=IF(B4="",0,MATCH(B4,B61:B88,-1))
```